# Menu wrongly animates when resizing the screen

Tags: html, css

My menu animation abruptly shows up when resizing the browser even with it set to be closed. It can only be seeing the problem when on a desktop. The only temporary solution I have is removing the transition but then I still want to implement the sliding animation.

this is the actual website: https://jxvicinema.github.io/juniper-roots-park-v2/

while this one is my repository: https://github.com/jxvicinema/juniper-roots-park-v2

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `display` property to your `.nav-links` and to `nav-active` like below.

```
.nav-links{
 display: none;
}
```

```
.nav-active{
 display: flex;
}
```

So for the animation to work instead of `display` property add `opacity` property.

```
.nav-links{
 opacity: 0;
}
```

```
.nav-active{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: still does not work.... i tried it but then the animation and transition wont be working anymore everytime I click the hamburger menu. :(